# Create a small table for each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list containing 20 datasets.
Each dataset is basically:

```
library(lubridate)

Date <- c("2010-01-28", "2010-01-28", "2010-02-28", 
           "2010-02-28", "2010-02-28", "2010-02-28", 
           "2010-01-28", "2010-01-28", "2010-02-28", 
           "2010-02-28")

Date <- as_date(Date)

Country <- rep("Bolivia", 10)

Value_A <- 1:10

df <- data.frame(Date, Country, Value_A)
```

So I made a small table containing the last value, the last - 1, and last - 7.

```
Time <- c("Today", "Yesterday", "One week ago")
Value <- c(df$Value_A[nrow(df)], df$Value_A[nrow(df)-1], df$Value_A[nrow(df)-7])

table <- data.frame(Time, Value)
```

```
tibble(table)

   Time         Value
  <chr>        <int>
1 Today           10
2 Yesterday        9
3 One week ago     3
```

**What I want is: do this same process, but automatically to each dataset in the list and store into another list.**

Ps: All datasets have the same variables, only changing the country.

Comment: How did you want to handle `Country` in your final list? Did you want to include countries as names of elements in your final stored list? Or just ignore?

Comment: Just ignore :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply` over your list (here called `lst`) of data frames and use a separate named function (or anonymous function as here):

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {
  nr <- nrow(x)
  data.frame(
    Time = c("Today", "Yesterday", "One week ago"),
    Value = c(x[["Value_A"]][nr], x[["Value_A"]][nr-1], x[["Value_A"]][nr-7])
  )
})
```

The result should be a list of data frames similar to what you have in your example. The `Country` is ignored as desired in the comments.